# How does an Android API get data from hardware?

Tags: android

How does an Android API get data from hardware? For example, how does the `getX()` function get the x-axis value from the accelerometer sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overly broad question: it varies depending on hardware data source. In the case of the example you picked, there is a native service that handles the JNI calls for Sensors (see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/native/android/sensor.cpp)): this fetches the data from a file descriptor that the hardware driver feeds.

Answer (score 1):

There are hardware interfaces which have software embedded. The subject Embedded systems gives a vast explanation of all this (Hardware having a software). Hence, the accelerometer sensors are embedded systems, having software in it, with which the device can interact to get the values.

Not sure you are convinced, as I haven't done my masters in Embedded, but have fairly good knowledge in it, and this was an attempt to help you understand

Comment: yeah i know each device has a specific driver......the question is how that getX() module access the driver to get the actual data? and I went through the sensor files in hardware package and couldn't find anything except the interface.

Comment: Not sure if I'm right..but usually the embedded programming has microprocessor code within it. So I guess we are restricted from using it, as we only have access to the interface, but not the programming in it

Comment: actually we can write our own code for that....if you design some hardware you need to change them too.......and thanks for your effort :)